# Least simultaneous quadratic non-residue

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Suppose $p,q$ are distinct primes with least quadratic non-residues $n_p$ and $n_q$ respectively. Can one bound the least $n$ for which $\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{n}{q}\right)=-1$ in terms of $n_p$ and $n_q$?

I had originally thought this would be a consequence of quadratic reciprocity and the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and so would be bounded by $n_pn_q$, but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, this is quite easy and only involves the multiplicative property of the quadratic residue.

If $n_p=n_q$ then we are done, because this very number is a simultaneous quadratic nonresidue. Otherwise we can without loss of generality suppose $n_p<n_q$. Then $(n_p|p)=-1$ while $(n_p|q)=1$. Also we know $(n_q|q)=-1$.
If we also have $(n_q|p)=-1$ then $n_q$ is a simultaneous quadratic nonresidue.
Otherwise $(n_q|p)=1$. Then by multiplicativity we have $(n_pn_q|p)=(n_pn_q|q)=-1$, so $n_pn_q$ is a simultaneous quadratic nonresidue.

Comment: Aha I suspected it should be simple!

Comment: The only fly in the ointment is if $n_p=q$ or $n_q=p$.  But the OP is perhaps not interested in these pathological  cases.

Comment: No, I am thinking that $p$ and $q$ are very near in size, which prohibits this obstruction.

Comment: Unfortunately, this argument seems to break down when there are three primes $p,q,r$. What could happen that $n_p=n_q<n_r$. Then if $(n_r|p)=-1$ and $(n_r|q)=1$ I don't see the same trick working.